# How do I get some test USDC for use on Solana devnet?

Tags: typescript, solana

I am familiar with 'airdrop' to get test Sol in devnet wallets:

```js
  var airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(publicKey, lamports);

  const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

  await connection.confirmTransaction({
    blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
    signature: airdropSignature,
  });
```

But how do I get test SPL tokens like USDC in Devnet? The [circle USDC docs](https://developers.circle.com/docs/usdc-on-testnet#usdc-on-solana-testnet) simply state:

> The USDC Solana SPL token has been deployed to the Devnet and is available on address 4zMMC9srt5Ri5X14GAgXhaHii3GnPAEERYPJgZJDncDU.

That's not a lot of information. I can happily generate wallets, and send SPL tokens between wallets once I have some SPL tokens - but **how do I get some test USDC for use on Solana devnet?**

Answer (score 6):

This website will send you devnet USDC https://usdcfaucet.com/

However, since mainnet and devnet USDC mint addresses are different it's easier to create your own mint and use it as USDC. This will give you more control on how much you can mint.

For testing purposes it's almost always better to [create your own token and use it as your "devnet USDC"](https://github.com/Bonfida/bonfida-utils/blob/main/js/src/token.ts#L11=).

Comment: That's a useful site, but how could I get USDC using JS/TS, eg, for running integration tests?

Comment: They do not document this part. What's you use case exactly? And does it require your test token to have this mint`4zMMC9srt5Ri5X14GAgXhaHii3GnPAEERYPJgZJDncDU`?

Because for testing purposes it's **almost always better** to create your own token and use it as your "devnet USDC" (JS example https://github.com/Bonfida/bonfida-utils/blob/main/js/src/token.ts#L11=)

Comment: Thanks @dr497. My use case is integration testing - much in the same way I do airdrop for Sol into a wallet and create transactions, I'd like get some USDC into a wallet and create transactions.